# (r ->) applicative functor

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

I am having some trouble understanding how the function instance `(->) r` of Applicative works in Haskell.

For example if I have

```
(+) <$> (+3) <*> (*100) $ 5
```

I know you get the result 508, I sort of understand that you take the result of `(5 + 3)` and `(5 * 100)` and you apply the `(+)` function to both of these.

However I do not quite understand what is going on. I assume that the expression is parenthesized as follows:

```
((+) <$> (+3)) <*> (*100)
```

From my understanding what is happening is that your mapping `(+)` over the eventual result of `(+3)` and then you are using the `<*>` operator to apply that function to the eventual result of `(*100)`

However I do not understand the implementation of `<*>` for the `(->) r` instance and why I cannot write:

```
(+3) <*> (*100)
```

How does the `<*>`, `<$>` operator work when it comes to `(->) r`?

Comment: I believe you are missing a `<$>`: `(+) <$> (+3) <*> (*100) $ 5`. It parses as `(((+) <$> (+3)) <*> (*100)) $ 5`.

Comment: @DanielWagner The `<$>`s got eaten by the markdown parser (but the `<*>`s didn’t, for whatever reason). I’ve added the necessary code escapes.

Comment: Ah i see thank you, i didn't know you had to escape the `<$>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<$>` is just another name for `fmap` and its definition for `(->) r` is `(.)` (the composition operator):

```
intance Functor ((->) r) where
  fmap f g = f . g
```

You can basically work out the implementation for `<*>` just by looking at the types:

```
instance Applicative ((->) r) where
  (<*>) :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
  f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)
```

You have a function from `r` to `a` to `b` and a function from `r` to `a`. You want a funtion from `r` to `b` as a result. First thing you know is you return a function:

```
\x ->
```

Now you want to apply `f` since it is the only item which may return a `b`:

```
\x -> f _ _
```

Now the arguments for `f` are of type `r` and `a`. `r` is simply `x` (since it alrady is of type `r` and you can get an `a` by applying `g` to `x`:

```
\x -> f x (g x)
```

Aaand you're done. [Here's a link to the implementation in Haskell's Prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-641).

Answer (score 6):

Consider the type signature of `<*>`:

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Compare this to the type signature for ordinary function application, `$`:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

Notice that they are extremely similar! Indeed, the `<*>` operator effectively generalizes application so that it can be *overloaded* based on the types involved. This is easy to see when using the simplest `Applicative`, `Identity`:

```
ghci> Identity (+) <*> Identity 1 <*> Identity 2
Identity 3
```

This can also be seen with slightly more complicated applicative functors, such as `Maybe`:

```
ghci> Just (+) <*> Just 1 <*> Just 2
Just 3
ghci> Just (+) <*> Nothing <*> Just 2
Nothing
```

---

For `(->) r`, the `Applicative` instance performs a sort of function composition, which produces a new function that accepts a sort of “context” and threads it to all of the values to produce the function and its arguments:

```
ghci> ((\_ -> (+)) <*> (+ 3) <*> (* 100)) 5
508
```

In the above example, I have only used `<*>`, so I’ve explicitly written out the first argument as ignoring its argument and always producing `(+)`. However, `Applicative` typeclass also includes the `pure` function, which has the same purpose of “lifting” a pure value into an applicative functor:

```
ghci> (pure (+) <*> (+ 3) <*> (* 100)) 5
508
```

In practice, though, you will rarely see `pure x <*> y` because it is precisely equivalent to `x <$> y` by the `Applicative` laws, since `<$>` is just an infix synonym for `fmap`. Therefore, we have the common idiom:

```
ghci> ((+) <$> (+ 3) <*> (* 100)) 5
508
```

---

More generally, if you see any expression that looks like this:

```
f <$> a <*> b
```

…you can read it more or less like the ordinary function application `f a b`, except in the context of a particular `Applicative` instance’s idioms. In fact, an original formulation of `Applicative` proposed the idea of “idiom brackets”, which would add the following as syntactic sugar for the above expression:

```
(| f a b |)
```

However, Haskellers seem to be satisfied enough with the infix operators that the benefits of adding the additional syntax has not been deemed worth the cost, so `<$>` and `<*>` remain necessary.

Comment: When I tried to run `Maybe (+) <*> Maybe 1 <*> Maybe 2` in ghci (7.10.3 and 8.0.1), I got `Data constructor not in scope: Maybe ...`. Did I miss something?

Comment: BTW, `Just (+) <*> Just 1 <*> Just 2` gives `Just 3`.

Comment: @LeeDuhem Oops, my bad, I don’t know what I was thinking when I wrote that. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a look at the types of these functions (and the definitions that we automatically get along with them):

```
(<$>) :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> r -> b
f <$> g = \x -> f (g x)

(<*>) :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> r -> b
f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)
```

In the first case, `<$>`, is really just function composition. A simpler definition would be `(<$>) = (.)`.

The second case is a little more confusing. Our first input is a function `f :: r -> a -> b`, and we need to get an output of type `b`. We can provide `x :: r` as the first argument to `f`, but the only way we can get something of type `a` for the second argument is by applying `g :: r -> a` to `x :: r`.

---

As an interesting aside, `<*>` is really the `S` function from [SKI combinatory calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus), whereas `pure` for `(-> r)` is the `K :: a -> b -> a` (constant) function.

Comment: Funny, how we have almost identical trains of thought. :D

Answer (score 4):

As a Haskell newbie myself, i'll try to explain the best way i can

The `<$>` operator is the same as mapping a function on to another function.

When you do this:

```
(+) <$> (+3)
```

You are basically doing this:

```
fmap (+) (+3)
```

The above will call the Functor implementation of (->) r which is the following:

```
fmap f g = (\x -> f (g x))
```

So the result of `fmap (+) (+3)` is `(\x -> (+) (x + 3))`

Note that the result of this expression has a type of `a -> (a -> a)`

Which is an applicative! That is why you can pass the result of `(+) <$> (+3)` to the `<*>` operator!

Why is it an applicative you might ask? Lets look the at the `<*>` definition:

```
f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Notice that the first argument matches our returned function definition `a -> (a -> a)`

Now if we look at the `<*>` operator implementation, it looks like this:

```
f <*> g = (\x -> f x (g x))
```

So when we put all those pieces together, we get this:

```
(+) <$> (+3) <*> (+5)
(\x -> (+) (x + 3)) <*> (+5)
(\y -> (\x -> (+) (x + 3)) y (y + 5))
(\y -> (+) (y + 3) (y + 5))
```

Comment: It is not `\x -> f x g x`, it is `\x -> f x (g x)`

Answer (score 3):

The `(->) e` `Functor` and `Applicative` instances tend to be a bit confusing. It may help to view `(->) e` as an "undressed" version of `Reader e`.

```
newtype Reader e a = Reader
  { runReader :: e -> a }
```

The name `e` is supposed to suggest the word "environment". The type `Reader e a` should be read as "a computation that produces a value of type `a` given an environment of type `e`".

Given a computation of type `Reader e a`, you can modify its output:

```
instance Functor (Reader e) where
  fmap f r = Reader $ \e -> f (runReader r e)
```

That is, first run the computation in the given environment, then apply the mapping function.

```
instance Applicative (Reader e) where
  -- Produce a value without using the environment
  pure a = Reader $ \ _e -> a

  -- Produce a function and a value using the same environment;
  -- apply the function to the value

  rf <*> rx = Reader $ \e -> (runReader rf e) (runReader rx e)
```

You can use the usual `Applicative` reasoning for this as any other applicative functor.